# SOLR - update a certain field value depending on the field value of another field

Tags: solr

I have a field whose default value is false:

```
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false"
  name="has_status" default="false" />
```

and I have another field:

```
<field indexed="true" multiValued="false"
  name="status_value"
 type="string" default="false" />
```

is there a way to calculate the value for has_status based on if status_value is not empty during indexing?
so, when a document is being indexed, if an item has status_list that we put "true" for has status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you using DataImportHandler, there are transformers for that. Otherwise, you want to use an UpdateRequestProcessor and [the nearly-identical example](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateRequestProcessor#Implementing_a_conditional_copyField) is on the wiki, or you can put something together with one of the [FieldMutating Update Processors](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_1_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/update/processor/FieldMutatingUpdateProcessorFactory.html).